# What do we know about "overconfidence" w.r.t asset characteristics and how can the overconfidence bias be implemented in a Markowitz portfolio modell?

Tags: portfolio-optimization, behavioral-finance

Disclaimer: I have a simnilar question already in quora with some answers which are good but not really satisfying (they were taken from Wikipedia or ChatGDP).

[image]

If I break down overconfidence into optimism (meaning it affects the mean vector) and overprecision (meaning it affects the covariance matrix) then I get two different answers:

Optimism means shifting the mean vector or its components in a certain way: If I shift them up simulataneously by a factor o>1 then i get the same allcoation. My interpretation is that if the investor is biased generally and doesn’t differentiate across all assets, then i get the same asset allocation as an unbiased manager.

If I shift each assets return differently I will end up with another efficient portfolio as in this case, it's similar to using subjective returns and I’m in the Black-Litterman-model, of which we know that it gives us another point on the efficient frontier.

Overprecision has a bit more bite. If I adjust the covariance matrix by applying a factor p<1 to each volatility term of each asset, then the covariance matrix is just multiplied by the scalar p^2 and nothing has changed regarding trhe structure of the covariances. However, if I apply them only on the diagonal (i.e. the variances in the covariance) then I quickly run into the problem that my overprecision-portfolios are not feasible.

If I manipulate the covariance terms only, then I run into another bias and the effects on my portfolio are counterintuitive as with increasing overprecision aka higher overconfidence, my asset allocation becomes more diversified as I split my wealth more evenly across assets due to the lower correlation among the assets- with higher overconfidence I would have expected that my allocation becomes more concentrated.

Here I attached a pic where I calculated the asset allocation for 10 assets woth o=0.2 vs. o=0.76 (the point where I still get a meaningful efficient frontier:

[image]
[image]

Furthermore, I attached a pic of my toy model that i quickly cobbled together to illustrate what I mean-yellow is the overprecision-/correlation neglect efficient frontier, dark green is the markowitz-efficient frontier:

[image]

In my toymodel, my results are either non-feasible or counterintuitive, thats why I don’t check ChatGDP anymore. However, I’d like to extend my previous question a bit: Does anyone know how overconfidence differs among various assets? e.g. higher volatility in an asset increases overprecision or I ignore the top-10 negative returns when calculating the mean vector?

Please feel free to post your ideas plus academic sources if you have any, Thank you! I appreciate any ideas :-)

EDIT: Please don’t be confused if the headlines say “correlation neglect”, I took these from another bias as they came quite handy